# How to make this complicated nested-folder-structure C library into one that is includable as a single <myc.h>

Tags: c, module, linker, shared-libraries

I just made this project to showcase how a project I am working on is roughly structured.

https://github.com/lancejpollard/example-c-library

It is a **library** (as opposed to an app or cli tool), and so I want it to be includable in any other C project (app, library, or otherwise) I might want to make. I want to use it in those projects like this:

```
#include <myc.h>
```

[I can't get it to compile though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59021186/how-to-properly-organize-multiple-c-and-h-files-in-different-directories-so-i).

If you take a look at the [Makefile](https://github.com/lancejpollard/example-c-library/blob/master/Makefile), you'll see what I'm trying to do. And if you look at each file in the [nested src directory](https://github.com/lancejpollard/example-c-library/blob/master/src/code/deeply/nested/foo.c), you'll see how I'm trying to *locally import each file within this library*. The errors I keep getting are along the lines of this:

```
/usr/local/include/myc.h:12:10: fatal error: 'a/foo.h' file not found
#include "a/foo.h"
```

I've changed it a million ways and it's always errors around the includes. If you take a look at the project, can you see how I should be writing the Makefile command exactly, and how I should be writing the includes within the project (in a relative sort of way)? And finally, after extensive research, I assume that I actually need to copy at least the `myc.h` header to the global path, so I can use it as a library in other projects. If this is incorrect please show me specifically how to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: `#include <something.h>` simply means that the compiler will look in a number of compiler-specific directories for the header, and if it is missing there, it won't be found. Meaning you'd either have to do a compiler-specific installation of your library, or provide it together with the compiler libs. There is nothing wrong with `#include "something.h"` however. This means that the compiler will look at the local project path first and if it doesn't find the header there, it will go look in the compiler-specific directories.

Comment: It's not a good idea to copy stuff to /usr/local at build time. That should normally be done at install time.

Comment: You probably need a `-I` option, such as `-Isrc/code/deeply/nested`.